# Undefined symbol: Swift.String.unicodeScalars.getter : Swift.String.UnicodeScalarView in XCode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm experiencing some issues trying to run the react-native project on my new M1 Mac.
This app was developed on an older Mac with Intel's chip and XCode version 12.5.1. and worked with no problem.
But when I try to run the same project on my new mac I'm getting these
[errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Atzr.png) (the list goes on)

Does anybody come across those issues and know how to fix them?

Comment: Are you trying to run the app on a simulator or a physical device?

Comment: I'm trying to run the app in simulator. I downgraded Xcode to 12.5.1 on the new mac, and everything works. I still didn't find any solution, that would work for me in XCode 13

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried excluding the arm64 architecture for Any iOS simulator SDK in the project level?

Project -> Build settings -> Architectures -> Excluded Architectures -> Debug

[image: Exclude arm64]

EDIT: I've posted as an answer because I can't attach images in the comments